# Getting selected colname as character in R/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, data-science

I'm trying to subset data based on selected column from **selectInput**. I have tried:

```
as.character(input$LabelBubble)
```

But this doesn't seem to extract the column text. Rest of the code where I select the columns below:

```
output$LabelBubble = renderUI(if(input$PlotType=="Dynamic Bubble Scatter"){
 mtext <- sapply(loadfile1(), is.factor)
 mcols<-as.list(colnames(loadfile1()[,mtext]))
 selectInput(
  "LabellBubble", 
  label = "Select factor variable",
  "",selectize=TRUE,multiple=FALSE,choices=mcols
 )
})
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is when there is only one column in `mtext`. `loadfile1()[,mtext]` returns a vector instead of an data.frame. If you are using `dplyr` you could do something like this instead with better results

```
mcols<-as.list(colnames(select(iris,one_of(names(mtext)[mtext]))))
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's a solution to what I didn't think of initially. But how would you go about extracting the name of the selected column from selectInput for a dynamic subset?